# How do I draw a rectangle onto an image with transparency and text

Tags: c#, gdi+

This is my first graphics based project and to begin with I need to be able to draw a rectangle onto a bitmap with transparency and text.

I'm not sure where to begin with this.  I've done a little research but can't seem to find an article that will allow me to add a semi transparent rectangle to an image.

What I will have is an image stream that I need to be able to manipulate.

Can someone please point me in the right direction for this?

A site with source would be great as I have never done any GDI work before.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
// Load the image (probably from your stream)
Image image = Image.FromFile( imagePath );

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
   // Modify the image using g here... 
   // Create a brush with an alpha value and use the g.FillRectangle function
}

image.Save( imageNewPath );
```

Edit: the code to create a semi transparency gray brush

```
Color customColor = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Gray);
SolidBrush shadowBrush = new SolidBrush(customColor);
g.FillRectangles(shadowBrush, new RectangleF[]{rectFToFill});
```

Answer (score 5):

To get started you need to create a Graphics context from the image that you want to modify. [See here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage.aspx)

```
// Create image.
Image imageFile = Image.FromFile("SampImag.bmp");

// Create graphics object for alteration.
Graphics newGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(imageFile);
```

Once you have the Graphics object you can use its many methods to draw onto the image. In your example you would use [DrawRectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawrectangle.aspx) method with an ARGB color to create a semi-transparent rectangle on your image.

You can then display the image to a screen control or save it to disk.