# Coloring area of an image on mouse click over picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, image-editing

I would like to be able to fill any given area of an image with a given color, much like you can use paint to fill a rectangle, circle or any other shape delimited by a color.

To make this simpler I already have made the picture box source image to have the same size as the picture box itself, which should make things a bit easier.

How can I do this given that I have a picture box with an image and an already defined color and the user only has to click over the picture box to fill in any area with such color.

```
void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   // The color to be used
   Color color = Color.Red;
   // Image has same dimensions as picturebox to make things easier
   Image img = pictureBox1.Image; 
   // Where it was clicked.
   Point clickCoords = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
   // Coloring that area clicked much like Paint does. How?
   ...
   // After coloring show the result in the picture box again
   pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

Thanks.

**EDIT: Example of my desired behavior.**

To make my goal obvious, let me add this small example.

You know MS Paint right?

You selected the pencil tool and start doing anything on the canvas, doesn't matter form or shape or even if the points your are doing with the pencil are connected or not.

Now you select the bucket tool and start clicking on the canvas. What will it do? Fill in the selected area according to the color you clicked over and how far she goes without changing with the color you have selected on the color pallet.

This is the behavior I want to emulate on my picture box mouse click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a flood-fill algorithm. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5133/Flood-Fill-Algorithms-in-C-and-GDI) should do the trick just fine. 
The algorithm recursively searched for neighboring uncolored pixels, until it hits a wall.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15889822/213550):

> ```
> // Load the image (probably from your stream)
> Image image = Image.FromFile( imagePath );
> using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
> {
>     Color customColor = Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Gray);
>     SolidBrush shadowBrush = new SolidBrush(customColor);
>     g.FillRectangles(shadowBrush, new RectangleF[] { rectFToFill });
> }
> image.Save( imageNewPath );
> ```

, but there is a one thing you missed - a `rectFToFill`, which you should define according your click event. There are a lot of strategies you can use, I suggest you to handle a `Drag` event or something like that, save the event start point and end point, after that define the rectangular you must fill:

[image]

You should examine the event points and after that create the `Rectangle(F)` structure using some of [its constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectanglef.rectanglef.aspx).
The [`Graphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics_methods.aspx) class has a dozen methods you can use to draw some shapes or lines on your `Image`.

Comment: Filling a rectangle or circle is no big deal if I know where it is. Except I won't drag the mouse over the picture box to define my shape to fill. I will only click one pixel and that pixel as well other pixels connected and all other pixels connected to them that share the same color will change to Red for example. See my edit to understand more clearly my goal. Thanks for the reply.