# Drawing (with double buffered graphics) from a Timer's thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, graphics, drawing

I have a User Control that I draw on periodically, and a timer in another class that, when it ticks, I wish to draw a string on the User Control.

Here is how I am drawing on the form with [Double Buffered graphics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.drawing.bufferedgraphics%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Private BufferedGraphicsContext Context:
Private BufferedGraphics BufferGraphics:

//...Later in UserControl_Load
    this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    this.Context = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
    this.Context.MaximumBuffer = new Size(this.Width + 1, this.Height + 1);
    this.BufferGraphics = this.Context.Allocate(this.CreateGraphics(), new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));


    //...Drawing to the form like you would regular Graphics
    this.BufferGraphics.Graphics.DrawEllipse(....

//paint event
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    this.BufferGraphics.Render(e.Graphics);
}


    //to trigger a paint event, I call this
    this.BufferGraphics.Render(Graphics.FromHwnd(this.Handle));
```

I've tried adding calling a method from the `Timer_Tick` event, but whenever I use `this.BufferGraphics.Graphics` I get a Null Pointer exception because `this.BufferGraphics` is null.

I've also found if I save the strings globally and then try to use `graphics.DrawString` in the `OnPaint` event, I run into some sort of deadlock issue and the strings are never changed.

So what's the best way to go about thread-safe drawing on controls in this instance? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using BufferedGraphics is almost never correct, *especially* not when you use it with threads.  You have to throw this away, you cannot make it work.  Use a normal Bitmap, pay attention to the pixel format, 32bppPArgb is almost always the correct choice.  And use *lock* carefully, only one thread can ever use it at the same time.

Comment: Hmmmm...I had been using BufferedGraphics to avoid the graphical flickering when drawing. Would I use something similar to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15889822/2752503) to draw using a bitmap? What if I'm not using an image, just drawing a rectangle on an UserControl or something like that.